# Evaluating the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{e^{x}-1} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I read somewhere that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{e^{x} - 1} = \frac{\pi^4}{15}$$

Does anyone see a way to prove this? My first idea was doing a contour integration and use the residue theorem, but that seems to be a lot of work so if anyone has a better idea I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: You can expand $\frac{1}{e^x-1} = e^{-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ into a geometric series. (The monotone convergence theorem says that's fine.) Then recall the $\Gamma$ integral and $\zeta$.

Comment: $\large 6\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$ is the given result

Comment: Here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function , you can see the integral representation of the zeta-function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}\,dx = \sum_{m\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^n e^{-mx}\,dx = n!\cdot\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^{n+1}} = n!\cdot\zeta(n+1).$$
In our case, $6\cdot\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $$e^x-1=t\implies x=\ln(t+1)$$$$e^x\ dx=dt\implies dx=\frac{dt}{t+1}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln(t+1))^3}{t}\frac{dt}{t+1}$$